# Determinant Property Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix and $a_{ij}$ be the entries of $A$ ($i,j \in \{1, \dots, n \}$).

If
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} = n$$
and
$$ a_{ij} \geq 0 \qquad (i,j \in \{1, \dots, n \})$$
then prove

(a) $|\det A| \leq 1$

(b) If $|\det A| = 1$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb C$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $|\lambda| = 1$.

---

Proving part (a) in the case $A$ is a diagonal matrix is easy, but I'm not sure how to go about the general case. Any hint or suggestion of a lemma/theorem/etc would be appreciated.

Not sure how I would go about part (b), but I imagine it would follow from the result obtained in (a).

Comment: Are we assuming $a_{ij}\ge0$ for all $i,j$? If not, (a) is certainly false, even for diagonal matrices.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I almost forgot to add that condition, but yes we are assuming $a_{ij} \geq 0$ for all $i, j$.

Comment: Looks like an extension of Perron Frobenius Theorem.

Comment: *Hint.* Suppose all columns of $A$ are non-zero. Let $B=AD^{-1}$ where $D=\operatorname{diag}\left(\sum_ia_{i1},\sum_ia_{i2},\ldots,\sum_ia_{in}\right)$. Then $B$ is a column-stochastic matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a different approach via Hadamard Determinant Inequality.

Let column $j$ of $A$ be given by $\mathbf a_j$
$\Big(\det\big(A^T A\big)\Big)^\frac{1}{n}$
$ \leq \Big(\prod_{j=1}^n \big \Vert \mathbf a_j\big \Vert_2^2\Big)^\frac{1}{n}=\Big(\prod_{j=1}^n \big \Vert \mathbf a_j\big \Vert_2\Big)^\frac{2}{n}$
$ \leq \Big(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n \big\Vert \mathbf a_j\big\Vert_2\Big)^2$
$\leq \Big(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n \big\Vert \mathbf a_j\big\Vert_1\Big)^2= \Big(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}\Big)^2 =1^2=1$
$\implies \vert \det A\vert \leq 1$
where the inequalities are **(i)** Hadamard Determinant Inequality, **(ii)** $\text{GM}\leq \text{AM}$, **(iii)** Triangle Inequality

with equality *iff* the columns of $A$ are mutually orthogonal, per (i), each column has the same norm, per (ii)-- which must be 1 since this implies $\prod_{j=1}^n \big \Vert \mathbf a_j\big \Vert_2^2 =1$-- and finally each column is $\propto$ a standard basis vector, per (iii).  That is, equality occurs *iff* $A$ is composed of $n$ linearly independent standard basis vectors aka *iff* $A$ is a Permutation Matrix (which, being orthogonal, necessarily has all eigenvalues on the unit circle).